# catalog is missing error on pg_dump postgresql 9.5

Tags: postgresql

I can't dumb the database in postgresql 9.5. The issue is only in 1 database and when we selecting the data from a view. It shows the catalog is missing 128 attribute(s). Is there any solution for this? There is no problem in table for select,Insert and delete operations. I can't update the VIEWS or remove them. Please help me for removing the views for solving the issues.

Comment: Please give us more information, like the commands you run, the error messages you get, output you see etc.

Comment: While running select query for view  , I am getting this errorSQL error:

ERROR:  catalog is missing 128 attribute(s) for relid 183772
LINE 1: select * from view_for_refund

Answer (score 3):

You have a corrupted database.

Try to find out what table is affected:

```
SELECT 183772::regclass;
```

Can you get a description of this table? How many columns should it have?

The error message is thrown if the number of attributes in the `pg_class` catalog does not correspond to the actual number of attributes in `pg_attribute`. These two queries should return the same value, but in your case the first will return 128 *more* than the second:

```
SELECT relnatts FROM pg_class
   WHERE oid = 183772;

SELECT count(*) FROM pg_attribute
   WHERE attrelid = 183772 AND attnum > 0;
```

I would restore from a backup.

Investigate which number of columns is correct.

Since the difference is exactly 128, perhaps a [bit flipped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_error) in RAM. Do you have [fault tolerant RAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECC_memory)? If not, maybe now you have an incentive to get some.

Check your hardware, especially your memory, for faults!

Get your oldest backup and see how things are there.
If it is *really* only one bit that flipped and the number from `pg_class` is off by 128, you could update `relnatts` for table 183772, and your problem would be fixed.

Comment: I run this Query , I got the result a view name. Is the views are corrupted and i can't drop the views that eturning the same error of 128 attribute missing

Comment: I have edited the answer with more information. Does that help you to understand the problem? How many attributes does the view have?

Comment: Thanks for your support and time. Fist query returns 223 and second returns 95.

Comment: I have extended the answer with some ideas how to deal with the problem.